# Unity 3d Google Play Service Android Configuration

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play-services

Before, when I tried to do an Android setup, I only had to write my `application id`, but now the below appears.

What am I doing wrong? What should I type into the text boxes?

[image: pic]

Comment: I think you can check the doc here: http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/android-sdksetup.html, and videos for quick set up [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9R8dVJr6Asw) and [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2LaBYDRR60g)

Comment: Thanks. These are not what I am searching for. But I found the solution. I just typed somethingIwant.GPGSIDs and it is working for now.